# PDF.svg method from svg2pdf.js library using jspdf does not render the expected output while running in loops

Tags: pdf, svg, promise, jspdf

I have an array of elements and for each element am trying to add the data of each element to the same PDF document so that it comes in different pages in the same document.

If I am calling the PDF.svg method only once, it works fine. but when I try to run the method for different data more than once to the same PDF document, my document content is distorted.

Here is my code:

```
let data = this.makeNewPdf(1, level,index);

    PDF.svg(data.img,{x:10,y:10,width:fileWidth,height:fileHeight}).then(()=>{

      PDF.save("newPdf")

    })

 

    data = this.makeNewPdf(9, level,index);

    PDF.svg(data.img,{x:10,y:10,width:fileWidth,height:fileHeight}).then(()=>{

      PDF.save("newPdf")

    })
```

If am running the first part of code alone, I am getting data inside the PDF document in the first page. But if am running this whole code or as a loop, my document has distorted shapes and images.

Since am new to frontend coding, kindly help me understand the problem here.

Comment: save returns a promise so you'd have to await till it finishes.